# If Value Exists in Any Column for a Row Automatically Flag Whole Row R

Tags: r

I subset my dataframe to include many variables and if a row contains a value of 1 for any column, I need to flag that row. What is a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `rowSums` :

```
df$has_1 <- rowSums(df == 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0
df

#  a b c has_1
#1 0 0 0 FALSE
#2 0 0 1  TRUE
#3 1 0 0  TRUE
#4 0 0 0 FALSE
#5 1 0 1  TRUE
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1), b = 0, c = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `any` with `apply`

```
df$has_1 <- apply(df, 1, any)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1), b = 0, c = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```